# Complete pom.xml for stormpath Web App with Java Servlet, JSP

Tags: stormpath

There is a tutorial for stormpath (online user management). The pom.xml that is provided at https://stormpath.com/blog/java-webapp-instant-user-management#maven is a bit confusing.

pom.xml

```
 4.0.0

com.stormpath.samples
stormpath-webapp-tutorial
0.1.0
war



        com.stormpath.sdk
        stormpath-servlet-plugin
        1.0.RC3.1


        javax.servlet
        javax.servlet-api
        3.0.1
        provided


        javax.servlet
        jstl
        1.2


        ch.qos.logback
        logback-classic
        1.0.13
        runtime






            org.apache.tomcat.maven
            tomcat7-maven-plugin
            2.2

                /
```

What kind of pom structure should this be? How would the complete and working pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

I am Stormpath's Java Developer Evangelist.

This section is in error in the blog. We are currently fixing it. I'll let you know when it's updated.

In the meantime, if you clone the Stormpath Java SDK at https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java.git, there's a fully functional servlet example in the `examples/servlet` folder. This has the proper `pom.xml` in it.

To build, you should be able to run:

`mvn clean install`

in the root folder of the project.

You can then drop `examples/servlet/target/stormpath-sdk-examples-servlet-1.0.0.RC-SNAPSHOT.war` into the container (like Tomcat) of your choice.

Feel free to drop us a line at: support@stormpath.com if you run into any trouble with this.

Comment: thx; looks like all .xml examples were not displayed correctly on the page.

Comment: FYI, I updated the blog post to fix the embedded code areas.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in my tutorial example. It works for me. Just add the `<dependencies>` part to the already existing default pom.xml of your project. Save the pom.xml and it will automatically download a bunch of .jar to your Libraries/Maven Dependencies.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>stormpath-servlet-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.RC9.1</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>        
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```